# Client rendering not working in IE 8

Tags: sharepoint-addin, internet-explorer, client-side-rendering

I have a SharePoint 2013 SP1. 
I have one app fields on the form. This field uses the client rendering. 
For all browsers except IE 8, everything works correctly. 
IE 8 is supported (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.15).aspx), but happening here strange things.

- For all mandatory fields not generated input
- For all non-text field (number, url, ...) is not generated input
- When saving a item, then is generated js error in clientforms.js

Print screens:

- https://imageshack.com/i/ip52eQK5p
- https://imageshack.com/i/idvGAfgPp

Any suggestions? Does somone know whether MS announced patch dealing with this issues?

Comment: I assume you're using JSLink on a list view? Can you provide any script errors or code?

Comment: I'm using JSLink on spfield for custom rendering (edit form). This means that the rendering of the entire form enters client-side rendering instead of server-side rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code was a problem, SP scripts in IE 8 is not working correctly, because:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
         for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
             if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
         }
         return -1;
    }
}
```

I solved otherwise, without the use of `Array.prototype`.